# Edit a single value in a specific row of a sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

Let's say my database shows some games with the attributes
_id | name | player1 | player2 | wins1 | wins2

Now I want to implement a method that increments wins1 or wins2 (due to paramater). But I can't figure out how to edit a single value without reentering all other values too. How can I do this?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a sql update query.

Example:

```
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
args.put(yourColumnName, newValue);
db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowID, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ContentValues like the example mentioned here http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial_database

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT, comment);
long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, null,values);
```